# AWS Lambda S3:::ObjectCreated:Put event returns invalid object key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-lambda

Good day!

I'm building a lambda function that is supposed to resize images saved in a particular bucket and re-save them in the same bucket under a different prefix (lambda will first check for this prefix to avoid infinite loops). When I attempt to upload the image '123.jpg' for instance, event.Resource[0].s3.object.key under the handler function will return 'undefined2018-02-26-08-40-37-DBAB838DACA3F368'

As you can imagine, this causes my lambda function to crash. Anyone have any ideas on this, please let me know as I've been knocking my head almost a week over this. Please find additional resources below. Note that I have also created a lambda event under s3 bucket settings:-

**LOGS for lambda Event**

```
event: { Records: 
 [ { 
     eventVersion: '2.0',
     eventSource: 'aws:s3',
     awsRegion: 'us-east-1',
     eventTime: '2018-02-26T08:40:37.281Z',
     eventName: 'ObjectCreated:Put',
     userIdentity: { principalId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX' },
     requestParameters: { sourceIPAddress: '8.8.8.8' },
     responseElements: 
     { 
       'x-amz-request-id': '05465A75942F4593',
       'x-amz-id-2': 'GWXnftcTHzfdAOuH40R2LO+h2laQhcO9eeU4JIzsRfYpL3HsDHmxzmqvE6lIlmAfcDO8O+gXU6U=' 
     },
     s3: { 
        s3SchemaVersion: '1.0',
        configurationId: '19945d41-71f2-4ae0-9004-b1c6c06b06da',
        bucket: { 
          name: 'sample-bucket-23',
          ownerIdentity: { principalId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX' },
          arn: 'arn:aws:s3:::sample-bucket-23' 
       },
       object: { 
          key: 'undefined2018-02-26-08-40-37-DBAB838DACA3F368',
          size: 355,
          eTag: '56b6395fe1bfea7cb98cd55d3cba3933',
          sequencer: '005A93C8053FEF92A2' 
       } 
    } 
 } 
 ] }
```

**Lambda Access Permissions**

```
{
  "roleName": "lambda_full_s3_v2",
  "policies": [
    {
      "document": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:s3:::sample-bucket-23"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "s3:PutObject",
              "s3:GetObject",
              "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:s3:::sample-bucket-23/*"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Action": [
              "logs:CreateLogGroup",
              "logs:CreateLogStream",
              "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
          }
        ]
      },
      "name": "oneClick_lambda_basic_execution_1519631544835",
      "type": "inline"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Could you please post your resize code?

Comment: my handler code is just a console log for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't an event triggered by your upload.  That is an event triggered by a new log file being written to your bucket, because you have configured your bucket to write its logs to itself, rather than to a different bucket in the same region.

> Amazon S3 uses the following object key format for the log objects it uploads in the target bucket:
>
> `TargetPrefixYYYY-mm-DD-HH-MM-SS-UniqueString`
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html

You will want to change your event trigger to watch only the prefix for images, reconfigure your Lambda code to ignore entries matching this pattern, or create a separate bucket for catching logs.

(I suspect the appearance of the string `undefined` at the beginning of the log object key is a console bug when you don't specify a prefix.  You could also change your bucket's logging configuration to add a prefix, e.g. `logs/` for the log files, if you want them written to this bucket.)